# Python selenium google map elements unable to locate

Tags: python, selenium

the code I'm trying to find elements are

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/async-local-kp/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/c-wiz/div').text)

rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/async-local-kp/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div').text
print(rating)
address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/async-local-kp/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div').text
print(address)
```

here is the element I'm trying to access please check the image [image: google page image]

the url of the google page is [google page link](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:14&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALeKk02wUsd-Mcth_6uw_tWVA9Lc0JmSIQ:1626679269004&q=general%20contractors,%20houston%20tx&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM3fe_zO7xAhWzIqYKHfIsBuIQjGp6BAgFEF8&biw=1366&bih=657#rlfi=hd:;si:14823770597215084948,l,Ch9nZW5lcmFsIGNvbnRyYWN0b3JzLCBob3VzdG9uIHR4SP-J0r_lgICACFo0EAAQARgAGAEYAhgDIh5nZW5lcmFsIGNvbnRyYWN0b3JzIGhvdXN0b24gdHgqBggDEAAQAZIBEmdlbmVyYWxfY29udHJhY3RvcqoBGxABKhciE2dlbmVyYWwgY29udHJhY3RvcnMoAA;mv:%5B%5B29.9428612,-95.1502967%5D,%5B29.5784016,-95.6639687%5D%5D)

but it says elements unable to find I'm using full xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just right click on what you need and press inspect
tried it on the review and it worked for me

SELECTOR:

```
#akp_tsuid37 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div.kp-blk.knowledge-panel.Wnoohf.OJXvsb > div > div.ifM9O > div > div.kp-header > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > span.Aq14fc
```

Comment: Do not use auto generated locators,  they are most unstable ones. locator writing is an skill and one should learn it for automation using Selenium.

Comment: @AliUmer, you are using the highly unstable one, do remember that

Answer (score 0):

Do not use auto generated locators, they are most unstable ones. locator writing is an skill and one should learn it for automation using Selenium.

try the below locator to retrieve google review rating :

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Google reviews')]/ancestor::span/preceding-sibling::span
```

and to get address use the below xpath :

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Address')]/../following-sibling::span
```

and use it in code like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
google_rating = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Google reviews')]/ancestor::span/preceding-sibling::span"))).text
print(google_rating)
address_from_google_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Address')]/../following-sibling::span"))).text
print(address_from_google_search)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong, not reliable locators.
Try this:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='kp-header']//g-review-stars/../span[@class='Aq14fc']").text
print(rating)
address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wDYxhc' and(contains(@data-attrid,'address'))]//div[@data-dtype='d3ifr']").text
print(address)
```